# Microsoft WORD table merge cells issue

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

In my MS WORD 2016 document, if I merge two cells I loose the data from those two cells. Moreover, I'm unable to enter any data into those two cells - I cannot even enter mouse cursor into that merged cell. I'm on Windows 10. Please advise.

**Screenshot of Merging two cells**

[image]

**After merging the above two cells data is lost in those cells - and cannot even get focus to that merged cell so I can enter something there**:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue with recent updates, only known fix for now is to uninstall the last update - KB4011039.

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/656572/merging-cell-in-word-table-issue/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c9c2c6ab-29f6-455a-bd23-10ee3d736992/officeword-2016-text-missed-from-tables-cell-after-kb4011039?forum=Office2016ITPro

Comment: link-only answers are not valid. At least summarize the content so that it's still valid when the external link dies

Comment: There really isn't much more than that, I edited to include the update reference and another link.
The bug has impacted a lot of users, I guess it will be fixed in a week or so.